# How to fix the problem that the text does not show in the frame?

Tags: beamer

How to fix the problem that the text does not show in the frame ?

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}       
    $$
s=\{(x,y)\ |\ \text{$x\neq y$ and $x, y$ occur in the same row or column or have the same symbol} \},
    $$
 and
    $$
 f=X\times X-(1_X\cup s).
    $$      
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please add a minimum working example (MWE) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

How about:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}


    $ s = \left\{  (x,y) \mid x \neq y \right.$ and $x, y$ occur in the same row or column or have the same symbol $\left.\right\}$

    and

        \[
            f=X\times X-(1_X\cup s).
        \] 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Long set descriptions are bad anyway, just use a sentence:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

$s$ is the set of pairs $(x,y)$ such that
$x\neq y$ and $x$, $y$ occur in the same
row or column or have the same symbol, and
\[
f=X\times X-(1_X\cup s).
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, you should never use `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Also, instead of

```
\{ x\ |\ P(x) \}
```

you should use

```
\{ x \mid P(x) \}
```